# Database Feature Comparison Matrix

Tags: comparison, database

Does anyone know of a table or chart that compares the features of SQL Server, SQLite, and MySQL (maybe Oracle too) ?

An example of what I'm looking for exists at [DEVX](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/29480), but doesn't include SQL Sever or SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comparison of Relational Database Management Systems**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Answer (score 0):

See : http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#comparison

*1 HSQLDB supports text tables.
*2 MySQL supports linked MySQL tables under the name 'federated tables'..
*3 Derby support for roles based security and password checking as an option..
*4 Derby only supports global temporary tables..
*5 The default H2 jar file contains debug information, jar files for other databases do not..
*6 PostgreSQL supports functional indexes..
*7 Derby only supports updatable result sets if the query is not sorted.
*8 Derby doesn't support standard compliant information schema tables..
*9 When using MVCC (multi version concurrency).
*10 Derby and HSQLDB don't hide data patterns well.
*11 The MULTI_THREADED option is not enabled by default, and not yet supported when using MVCC.
*12 Derby doesn't support the EXPLAIN statement, but it supports runtime statistics and retrieving statement execution plans.
*13 Derby doesn't support the syntax LIMIT .. [OFFSET ..], however it supports FETCH FIRST .. ROW[S] ONLY.
*14 Using collations. *15 Derby and H2 support ROW_NUMBER() OVER().